# How to handle the exception for oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException

Tags: oracle, exception, struts

I want to handle the exception for oracle disconnect at runtime. Now my current code in web.xml is

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.transaction.xa.XAException</exception-type>
        <location>/ExceptionHandler.do</location>
    </error-page>
```

Currently , can't handle that exception. Let me know your advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Zay Ya,**

Put your database connectivity code into a try catch block and in catch block return some string **`"error"`**.

**For Example :-**

```
try{

   // Database Connectivity code here

} catch(javax.transaction.xa.XAException ex){

   ex.printStackTrace();
   return "error";
}
```

Now handle this into your **`struts.xml`** file

```
<action name="ActionName" class="ActionClassName" method="MethodName">
    <result name="success">Success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">Error.jsp</result>
</action>
```